# Question on a basic classical mechanics problem

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

In my book the solution begins with

$$T=\frac{1}{2}M\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+2\dot{x}\dot{y}\cos\alpha)$$

I was wondering why the kinetic energy for the small block is $\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+2\dot{x}\dot{y}\cos\alpha)$. Where is the third term coming from? I thought $\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the position of the block at an arbitrary point in time in the plane of the picture. Assume the origin is on the ground where we start measuring the displacement $x$.

The horizontal displacement from the origin of the block is $x+y \cos \alpha$ while its vertical displacement from the origin is $y \sin \alpha$. We can write these as a pair of coordinates $(x+y \cos \alpha,y \sin \alpha)$.

To get the velocity we just differentiate w.r.t. time, so $\vec v=(\dot x+\dot y \cos \alpha,\dot y \sin \alpha)$.

The kinetic energy is given by $$T=\frac12 m |\vec v|^2=\frac12 m[(\dot x+\dot y \cos \alpha)^2+(\dot y \sin \alpha)^2]$$ and the result follows from here.

What probably confused you is the fact that in this problem $y$ is not defined as vertical displacement (look at the picture).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the big block is moving too. This small detail cost me 2 hours of time ....